# Using For-Each loop to create a TableView

Tags: c#, android, ios, unity-game-engine, tableview

I'm using a Unity3D Asset to create a TableView for my App. However when I attempt to move from one object to another in my `for-each` loop, It only displays the last Object in the response. Here is what I mean:

[image]

**Here is my code for attempting to create the cells (FYI I am using GameSparks as the backend service):**

```
//Will be called by the TableView to know how many rows are in this table
public int GetNumberOfRowsForTableView (TableView tableView)
{
    return 10;
}

//Will be called by the TableView to know what is the height of each row
public float GetHeightForRowInTableView (TableView tableView, int row)
{
    return (m_cellPrefab.transform as RectTransform).rect.height;
}

//Will be called by the TableView when a cell needs to be created for display
public TableViewCell GetCellForRowInTableView (TableView tableView, int row)
{
    LeaderboardCell cell = tableView.GetReusableCell (m_cellPrefab.reuseIdentifier) as LeaderboardCell;

    if (cell == null) {
        cell = (LeaderboardCell)GameObject.Instantiate (m_cellPrefab);
        new GameSparks.Api.Requests.LeaderboardDataRequest ().SetLeaderboardShortCode ("High_Score_Leaderboard").SetEntryCount (100).Send ((response) => {
            if (!response.HasErrors) {
                resp = response;
                Debug.Log ("Found Leaderboard Data...");

            } else {
                Debug.Log ("Error Retrieving Leaderboard Data...");
            }
        });
    }

    foreach (GameSparks.Api.Responses.LeaderboardDataResponse._LeaderboardData entry in resp.Data) {
        int rank = (int)entry.Rank;
        //model.Rank =rank;
        string playerName = entry.UserName;
        cell.name = playerName;
        string score = entry.JSONData ["SCORE"].ToString ();
        cell.SetScore(score);
        //string fbid = entry.ExternalIds.GetString("FB").ToString();
        //model.facebookId = fbid;
        Debug.Log ("Rank:" + rank + " Name:" + playerName + " \n Score:" + score);
    }
    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You first instantiate the cell variable and then you do the for loop over your resp.Data. The problem is, that you just go through all the data and with each iteration you set the name and set the score. With each iteration you overwrite these values and then at the end, when the loop ends you return the last version of the cell.
According to the comment that you have above the GetCellForRowInTableView method you should not really loop in there because this method is supposed to be called once for every item. Therefore, what you want to do instead of looping is something like this:

```
public TableViewCell GetCellForRowInTableView (TableView tableView, int row)
{
    LeaderboardCell cell = tableView.GetReusableCell (m_cellPrefab.reuseIdentifier) as LeaderboardCell;

    if (cell == null) {
        cell = (LeaderboardCell)GameObject.Instantiate (m_cellPrefab);
        new GameSparks.Api.Requests.LeaderboardDataRequest ().SetLeaderboardShortCode ("High_Score_Leaderboard").SetEntryCount (100).Send ((response) => {
            if (!response.HasErrors) {
                resp = response;
                Debug.Log ("Found Leaderboard Data...");

            } else {
                Debug.Log ("Error Retrieving Leaderboard Data...");
            }
        });
    }

    var entry = resp.Data[row];
        int rank = (int)entry.Rank;
        //model.Rank =rank;
        string playerName = entry.UserName;
        cell.name = playerName;
        string score = entry.JSONData ["SCORE"].ToString ();
        cell.SetScore(score);
        //string fbid = entry.ExternalIds.GetString("FB").ToString();
        //model.facebookId = fbid;
        Debug.Log ("Rank:" + rank + " Name:" + playerName + " \n Score:" + score);

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: The issue with this solution is that the data coming back from the GameSparks server cannot be indexed for some reason, Is there anyway I can apply this solution by turning the data into JSON?

Comment: How about using linq and the method ElementAt (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb299233(v=vs.100).aspx) - if you can enumerate your resp with a foreach loop then this should work as well. Then instead of resp.Data[row] you will have resp.ElementAt(row).

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is a classic issue with foreach loop. Basically, the system overwrites the current reference with the new indexed item in the collection. So despite the fact you are storing the values in local variable, your entry reference gets overwritten and then all values are pointing to the same entry object in the end.

The solution would be to create a local entry reference:

```
   foreach (GameSparks.Api.Responses.LeaderboardDataResponse._LeaderboardData entry in resp.Data) {
        var localEntry = entry; // New line
        int rank = (int)localEntry.Rank; // entry is replaced with local
        string playerName = localEntry.UserName; 
        cell.name = playerName;
        string score = localEntry.JSONData ["SCORE"].ToString (); line 
        cell.SetScore(score);
        Debug.Log ("Rank:" + rank + " Name:" + playerName + " \n Score:" + score);
    }
```

EDIT: I see you are returning cell outside the loop so even though the loop fixed one issue, you had another one elsewhere.

See in each loop, you are populating the cell data. But in each loop you are overwritting the cell data. And in the end, you return with the last value.
Either you can return an array of cell and you create the item with the array, or pass an array of item to the method so for each iteration of the loop, you also set the values of the matching item (using the index).

Comment: I attempted to use this solution however the same issue occurs, I have also tried to fix it by putting the `return cell;` within the for-each loop